# convert for loop to the Linq lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

how i can convert this loop to the Linq lambda .

I have define a dictionary

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(1,"Test");
        dictionary.Add(2,"Test2");
        dictionary.Add(3,"Test3");
        dictionary.Add(4,"Test4");
```

and want to navigate through it and make a string according to the number value

```
       int number = 10; // I am hard coded this number for this example
       string somevalue = string.Empty;
       int somekey = 0;

   foreach (var simple in dictionary )
         {
             while (number>=simple.Key)
             {
                  somevalue += simple.Value;
                  somekey -= simple.Key;
             }
         }
   }
```

It works fine with simple loop and will return `Test4Test4Test2`, just need to convert it to a lambda expression.

Comment: What language is this?  You can't combine `+=` with declaration in C#.

Comment: it is c# . i just do the simple string concating with `+=`

Comment: Obviously your code is invalid and won't compile. First of all as recursive said, you can't use the value of `value` before it has been assigned, which is what you're trying to do with the `+=` operator, second you're loop with be endless, since you never alter the value of `number'.

Comment: You are right, I just update the code

Comment: @fatima: You still have an extra closing curly brace at the end.  If you take that out, your `while` loop is an infinite loop that never terminates.  When you update your code, try executing it to make sure it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
List<string> list = dictionary
   .Select(kv => string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(kv.Value, kv.Key)))
   .ToList();
```

With you sample: `"Test"` ( `TestTest` if the key is 2)

However, your loop does not compile and it's not clear for what you need `number` when the key already indicates the number of repetitions.

Comment: thank for reply , I just add more context to my question . I try your solution but I did not get my expected result